# Python / Django Queries - Append Raw SQL To Model Object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to add raw sql to a Django model object.  The query in SQL I would like to perform without writing the entire thing. Raw SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM elements ORDER BY IF(elements.order=0, 99999, elements.order) ASC
```

Basically, order elements by the order field but if their order value is '0' they are ordered last.

I have tried using extra() or appending raw() without any great success...  I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Elements.objects.all().extra("ORDER BY IF(order=0, 99999, order)")  ## or
Elements.objects.all().raw("ORDER BY IF(order=0, 99999, order)")
```

Any clue???

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Do this.

```
results = list( Element.objects.filter(whatever).exclude( order__isnull=True ).order_by( order ) )
results.extend( Element.objects.filter(whatever).filter( order__isnull=False ) )
```

That will avoid overly complex SQL.

Try this.  It's really fast.  It may be faster than SQL.

```
def by_order( item ):
    return item.order if item.order is not None else 2**32
results = list( Element.objects.filter(whatever).all() )
results.sort( key=by_order )
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like the answer and the suggestion!  Although, to answer the original question, is it possible to do what I asked?

Answer (score 0):

Put the custom SQL in the `select` of the `extra`, and then use `order_by` to order by the new value:

```
Elements.objects.all().extra(
    select={
        'my_order_no': 'IF(elements.order=0, 99999, elements.order)'
    },
    order_by='my_order_no'
);
```

[`extra` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)